# caliburn winrt usercontrol and capturing custom event

Tags: windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I made my own slider as user control with some custom properties and one custom event. Everything works fine, but recently I start using Caliburn Micro, and I don't know how to capture my custom event.

Previously I used:

```
<my:RadialSlider x:Name="slider" WedgeAngle="270" ..... AngleChanged="slider_AngleChanged" />
```

and

```
public void slider_AngleChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
.... something ....
}
```

Now, in Caliburn project I tried:

```
<my:RadialSlider x:Name="slider" WedgeAngle="270" ..... cal:Message.Attach="[Event AngleChanged] = [Action slider_AngleChanged($eventArgs)]" />
```

and in my ViewModel:

```
public void slider_AngleChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    .... something ....
    }
```

But, this doesn't work...

So, how to capture this event?

Slider UC code-behind:

```
public delegate void AngleChangedEventHandler(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e);

    public sealed partial class RadialSlider : UserControl
    {
public event AngleChangedEventHandler AngleChanged;

        private void OnAngleChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AngleChanged != null)
                AngleChanged(this, e);
        }

public static readonly DependencyProperty WedgeAngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WedgeAngle", typeof(double), typeof(RadialSlider), new PropertyMetadata((double)270, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyWedgeAngleChanged)));
        public double WedgeAngle
        {
            get { return (double)this.GetValue(WedgeAngleProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(WedgeAngleProperty, value); }
        }

private static void OnPropertyWedgeAngleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as RadialSlider).UpdateControls();
            if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
            {
                (sender as RadialSlider).OnAngleChanged(new ValueChangedEventArgs((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue));
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: normal, i will update post with example

Comment: Is your event a RoutedEvent or a normal .NET event ?

Comment: Try to use a RoutedEvent or a RoutedUiEvent and see if it works, it is probably the reason because Triggers assume the event is routed i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a routed event. This has to do with how events bubble up the visual tree and how Caliburn.Micro attaches itself to them. Standard events should be avoided on controls or UI widgets in any tech using Xaml as the loose out on some pretty funky features (bubble up / down).